# How to run through multiple if statements

Tags: java

When I run this code it will only do some of the if statements until it finds one that is true. How to I make it run through all of the if statements.

```
for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++) {
    for (int r = 0; r <= 9; r++) {
        try {
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c - 1][r - 1] < 20) Sprite.count++; //top left
            System.out.println("if 1");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c - 1][r] < 20) Sprite.count++; //left
            System.out.println("if 2");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c - 1][r + 1] < 20) Sprite.count++;  //buttom left
            System.out.println("if 2");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c][r + 1] < 20) Sprite.count++;  //buttom    
            System.out.println("if 4");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c + 1][r + 1] < 20) Sprite.count++;  //buttom right  
            System.out.println("if 5");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c + 1][r] < 20) Sprite.count++;  // right    
            System.out.println("if 6");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c + 1][r - 1] < 20) Sprite.count++;  // right to
            System.out.println("if 7");
            if (Sprite.mine_1[c][r - 1] < 20) Sprite.count++;  //top
            System.out.println("if 8");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make all conditions true or use switch statement

Comment: placing braces around the code block of if and new line between each if block will help you answer your question by yourself.

Comment: Don't silently ignore the exception you get. Most likely you try to access an array element that does not exist.

Comment: @Henry in this case its fine

Comment: As I already tried to tell you, there is no way that an `if` is skipped in your code unless you get an exception. For example if `c=0` the first `if` tries to access `Sprite.mine_1[-1]` which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

i just ended up doing it the long way.

```
    for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)//if number 1
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
            try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c-1][r-1]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1; //top left



        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }       

    for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)// number2
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
        try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c-1][r  ]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1; //left


    }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }

            for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)// number3
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
        try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c-1][r+1]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1;    //buttom left


    }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }


            for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)// number4
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
        try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c  ][r+1]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1;    //buttom    


    }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }


            for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)// number5
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
        try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c+1][r+1]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1;    //buttom right  


    }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }



            for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)// number6
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
        try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c+1][r  ]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1;    // right    


    }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }



            for(int c=0; c<=9; c++)// number7
    {
        for(int r=0; r<=9; r++)
        {       
        try 
        {

        if(Sprite.mine_1[c+1][r-1]<20) Sprite.mine_2 [c][r] +=1;    // top right


    }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) 
        {               
        }       

        }
    }
```

Comment: A better solution would be to avoid getting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will be time consuming as multi-level of loops, but still this can check all the cases for particular c and r values...

```
for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
{
    for (int r = 0; c <= 9; r++)
    {
        for (int i = -1; c <= 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; c <= 1; j++)
            {
               try
               {
                   if(Sprite.mine_1[c+i][r+j] < 20 && ( i != 0 || j != 0 ) )
                  {
                     Sprite.count++; 
                  }  
               catch (Exception e)

                {
                  // print what you want
                }
             }

         }

    }

}
```

and for better cases try something like this to avoid IndexOutOfBoundException 
starts c and r with 1 to 10 but with actual array of 0 - 11

```
for (int c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
{
    for (int r = 1; c <= 10; r++)
    {
        for (int i = -1; c <= 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; c <= 1; j++)
            {
               try
               {
                   if(Sprite.mine_1[c+i][r+j] < 20 && ( i != 0 || j != 0 ) )
                  {
                     Sprite.count++; 
                  }  
               catch (Exception e)

                {
                  // print what you want
                }
             }

         }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you post the exact same answer again?

Comment: I delete that as it is being downvote, because it mistakenly downvoted before editing.